# If customers can only use a maximum of 1,000 mileage points each time, how do I write a SQL statement that displays the following?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL and have been playing around with it. However, I've stumbled upon a problem that I cannot seem to solve:

If customers can only use a maximum of 1,000 mileage points each time, how do I write a SQL statement that displays their number, name, and usable mileage at this moment (which cannot exceed 1,000)?

The table below is what I am using to answer this question.

I am using SQL*Plus. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I suspect the greatest(totalmileage) function might be used here, but I haven't had much luck in figuring out exactly how.

```
SQL> select * from customers;

CNU CNAME      ACCOUNTBALANCE TOTALMILEAGE
--- ---------- -------------- ------------
101 Andy                85.25         2152
102 Betty                 170          108
103 Cindy              -55.13            3
104 David             1308.02         5510
105 Ellen               99.77        11150
106 Frank                -.02           80
```

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement to return the available miles, which will be either `1000` if they have this many or more, or the balance if they have less:

```
SELECT CNU,
       CNAME,
       ACCOUNTBALANCE,
       TOTALMILEAGE,
       CASE WHEN COALESCE(TOTALMILEAGE, 0) > 1000
            THEN 1000
            ELSE COALESCE(TOTALMILEAGE, 0) END AS USABLEMILEAGE
FROM customers
```

Comment: You are amazing, thank you so much -- worked like a charm! I was fiddling madly with "Greatest" all day; it seems that I was trying out the wrong command.

Comment: Just be careful of Null values :)

Comment: @Joe I would say that the best design practice for the table would be to make the balance columns not nullable, but yes we could add logic to handle nulls as well.